# How do I structure my NPM package to contain subfolders for types and functions?

Tags: typescript, npm, package.json, tsconfig, monorepo

I am trying to create a NPM package that can be used locally to share types and functions in the rest of my project. Let's call my project *wordle*. As you could probably tell by the mention of types, this is a TypeScript project. Ideally I want to be able to import types and functions in the following way:

```
import { Move } from "wordle-shared/types";
import { getValidWords } from "wordle-shared/utils"
```

Can someone explain how I would need to structure this NPM package to achieve the desired structure? I've seen people use @ in their package name (e.g. @wordle-shared), if this is required, that is fine.

So far I have the following folder structure

```
wordle-shared
├── src
│   ├── types
│   └── utils
├── package.json
├── tsconfig.json
├── .gitignore
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, there needs to be a build step for TS to load your package correctly, because it will be looking for `d.ts` files.

You could maybe use git submodules to inject the library code directly in your project instead of deploying it and installing it as a package. I never tried it, nor did I try workspaces, but I think it would be transparent to TS, then you would not have to build and the library would still be versioned.

Here is one way to do it as a package with `tsc`:

```
wordle-shared
├── src
│   ├── types.ts
│   └── utils.ts
├── dist
│   ├── types.d.ts
│   └── utils.js
│   └── utils.d.ts
├── package.json
├── tsconfig.json
├── .gitignore
```

```json
// wordle-shared package.json
{
    "type": "module",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "exports": {
        "./utils": {
            "import": "./dist/utils.js",
            "types": "./dist/utils.d.ts"
        }, "./types": {
            "types": "./dist/types.d.ts"
        }
    }
}
```

```json
// wordle-shared tsconfing.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist",
    },
    "include": ["src"],
}
```

```json
// .gitignore
node_modules
dist
```

Then you can add the shared library as a dependency

```json
// wordle package.json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "wordle-shared": "^1.0.0",
  }
}
```

You will need this compiler option for TS to detect the `types` fields in the library package.json

```json
// wordle tsconfing.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "moduleResolution": "nodenext"
    },
}
```

Comment: This seems to be what I'm looking for:) Thanks! However, ran into problems as one of the packages I would like to include in my monorepo is firebase functions, and as it turns out, it does not really like importing local packages:/

Answer (score 2):

Can't comment yet, but have you tried [npm workspaces](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/workspaces)? It would result in a structure similar to what you described. Each package manages their own dependencies and can import from eachother.

```
// ./wordle/package.json
{
    "name": "wordle",
    "workspaces": [
        "wordle-shared",
        "wordle-project-a",
    ]
}
```

```
.
├── node_modules
│   ├── .package-lock.json
│   ├── wordle-project-a -> ../wordle-project-a
│   └── wordle-shared -> ../wordle-shared
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── wordle-project-a
│   ├── package.json
│   └── src
│       └── index.ts
└── wordle-shared
    ├── package.json
    ├── types
    │   └── index.ts
    └── util
        └── index.ts
```

With this setup, you can use `wordle-shared`'s exports in `wordle-project-a` as you described. If you insist on keeping them in a separate `src/` directory, you can set up a [path alias in `tsconfig.json`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#paths).